# How to replace selected string from content editable div?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, contenteditable

I'm trying to replace chapter titles from the contenteditable="true" div tag by using python and selenium-webdriver, at first I am searching for the chapter title, which is usually at first line... then I'm replacing it with empty value and saving.. but it's not saving after refreshing browser. But I see that code is working. Here is my code

```
##getting content editable div tag
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.trumbowyg-editor')
### getting innerHTML of content editable div
chapter_html = input_field.get_attribute('innerHTML')
chapter_content = input_field.get_attribute('innerHTML')
if re.search('<\w*>', chapter_html):
  chapter_content = re.split('<\w*>|</\w*>', chapter_html)
  first_chapter = chapter_content[1]
  ### replacing first_chapter with ''
  chapter_replace = chapter_html.replace(first_chapter, '')
  ### writing back innerHTML without first_chapter string
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1];",input_field, chapter_replace)
  time.sleep(1)
  ## click on save button
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.save-button').click()
```

How I can handle this ? It is working when I'm doing manually(I mean it probably can't be site problem/bug)... Please help ...

Relevant HTML is following:

```
<div class="trumbowyg-editor" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Chapter 1</p>
    <p> There is some text</p>
    <p> There is some text</p>
    <p> There is some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant _HTML_ along with the exact _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: <div class="trumbowyg-editor" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true">
<p>Chapter 1</p>
<p> There is some text</p>
<p> There is some text</p>
<p> There is some text</p>
</div>

So basically I Need to remove "Chapter 1" from the first line. It always is written on the first line or second line

Comment: Can you please edit the main question with this _HTML_ for a quick analysis?

Comment: Yes, I edited. is it ok for now?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to replace the chapter title with empty value you have to induce *WebDriverWait* with `expected_conditions` clause set to `visibility_of_element_located` and can use the following block of code :

```
page_number = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='trumbowyg-editor' and @contenteditable='true']/p[contains(.,'Chapter')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('innerHTML')", page_number)
#or
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('innerText')", page_number)
#or
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('textContent')", page_number)
```

Comment: this code is giving following error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='trumbowyg-editor' and @contenteditable='true']//following::p[contains(.,'Chapter')]"}

Comment: I tried following:

`page_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='trumbowyg-editor' and @contenteditable='true']//p[contains(.,'Chapter')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('innerHTML')", page_number)`
as you can see the differences, I havent use following:: before p[]. 
But anyway in debug mode I can see that page_number is getting correct value, but still not removing it from the body

Comment: I think the issue not connecting with finding the correct p[], the issue is that remove function not working

Comment: Actually the same behavior, page_number getting 'Chapter' value and not removing from the text

Comment: BTW, Can we write the regex in contains statement? Maybe there is spaces or numbers after chapter, (e.g. Chapter 1) or maybe chapter is UPPERCASE, e.g.  CHAPTER 1

Comment: Can you try the third option and update me the status please?

Comment: do you have any other suggestion?